# Should I schedule an operation performed in an Android custom Application class onCreate() method?

Tags: android

I have an Android application which depends on the value returned by a webservice. This value changes only once a week. Clients should detect this changed value, but the exact time they detect this change is not really important, 12 to 24 hours later should be no problem.

My current implementation starts an IntentService in the onCreate() method of my custom Application class which retrieves the value from the webservice. I also persist the last retrieved value in the SharedPreferences, so the application does not have to wait until this value is retrieved.

Now my question is if it is necessary to schedule the retrieval of this value after it's first retrieval in the onCreate() method, lets say after 12 hours. I know the onCreate() method is called only once in the lifecycle of an application, but I do not know how likely it is an application will be terminated by the Android system. Is it reasonable to assume that the application will be terminated enough times so that scheduling is not necessary? And in the case I should schedule the operation, what will be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you used onCreate, I don't think you'd have any guarantees that it would be called a second time. E.g. if the user plugs their phone in to charge, has go-to-sleep turned off and leaves your app running for days on end. Very unlikely, but not impossible. If I were you I'd set up some sort of scheduled task. Maybe this link will help - http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html.

Comment: The scenario you outline is the reason I asked this question :) The code example with a Handler and the postDelayed() method in the linked article looks good to me, I assume it also is an efficient solution?

Comment: I am going to implement the solution outlined in your linked article. If you place this in an answer of your own, I will accept your answer. If not, I will answer my own question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `onCreate()`, I don't think you'd have any guarantees that it would be called a second time. E.g. if the user plugs their phone in to charge, has go-to-sleep turned off and leaves your app running for days on end. Very unlikely, but not impossible.

If I were you I'd set up some sort of scheduled task. Maybe this link will help:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

The example uses an `OnClickListener` to cancel the task.

```
OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
   }
};
```

You would want to put this elsewhere, in `onDestroy()` perhaps.

Comment: I implemented this, works like a charm. I placed the call to handler.removeCallbacks() in the onTerminate() method of my Application class. But I don't think this is really necessary, because it is my understanding that in the case the application is terminated, the main thread of the application is also closed, and all posted messages in this threads message queue are also removed.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the posted messages. I'd explicitly remove them myself if possible. Also, `Application.onTerminate()` is not guaranteed to run - *It will never be called on a production Android device* - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29.

Comment: Ah good point regarding onTerminate(), I did not know that. As for removing the messages: according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29 messages are dropped if the looper is terminated, which happens if a process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, as I have had similar design challenges. Both have pros and cons.

**Option A**

You could have a splash screen, like many apps, and use the [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class to make web requests and update your shared preferences. You could set a custom timeout so the app doesn't get stuck on the splash screen for too long. No matter what the result, if it updated or did not, you can then load what ever is in sharedPreferences and use that for app usage on that run.

The good thing about this is that every time the app starts you won't have to worry if the data is up to date or not, as you will just go and get it. For performance updates you could also store the last time the sharedPref value was updated (e.g. you got the value less than 12 hours ago) and therefore skip the web request - the result makes your splash screen quite quick to come and go.

**Option B**

You could use an Alarm via the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), this is would be much better than a service which would be a unnecessary battery drain. There is even an enum for the interval of a day "INTERVAL_DAY". When the alarm is triggered a broadcast recevier will execute your custom code that would make the web request and get the values and store them. You can state if the Alarm repeats is a single use.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: there aren't the only options just the ones i picked out of relevance.

Comment: I do not want to use a splash screen, because my app just displays sport results, so my users do not want to wait if it is not needed. Furthermore, option A does not handle the scenario outlined by Paul Grime in his comment to my question. Option B is a nice way of handling my problem, but I think it is overly complex for my needs. But thanks for you input anyway.